# Prevent to call The didExitRegion() method of MonitorNotifier callback automatically

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

When the application goes to the background, didExitRegion() of MonitorNotifier callback is called automatically.

How can I prevent that automatic call?

```
@Override
    public void **onBeaconServiceConnect**() {
        System.out.println("call onBeaconServiceConnect()");
        try {
            System.out.println("call notifier ");


            mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
            mBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(mAllBeaconsRegion);


            mBeaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
                @Override
                public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                    System.out.println("monitor enter " + region.getId1());
                }


                @Override
                public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                    System.out.println("monitor exit " + region.getId1());
                }


                @Override
                public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
                    System.out.println("monitor " + region.getId1());
                }
            });

            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(mAllBeaconsRegion);

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("call notifier exception"+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please watch your spelling and grammar if you want answers. I fixed that for you.

Comment: This is not expected behavior.  There may be a problem with the way this is programmed it your app that is causing the isdue.  Please edit your question to show your code.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you using BackgroundPowerSaver?  Do you customize the scan intervals in the library?  How long after you put the app to the background do you get the exit callback?

Comment: This is the code snippet of BackgroundPowerSaver.
 
BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);                   
            mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(1);
            mBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);
            mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1);

What i need to change?

Comment: The app goes in background,The exit method calls after 4-5 second.